# How to send a dynamically generated file that exceeds heroku 30 sec limit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an action on my RoR project that generates a large zip with dynamic data, it takes more than the 30 seconds allowed by heroku. 
Heroku allows the request to last longer than 30 seconds if I send data back to the client,so:

1. how can i solve this (I guess some sort of jquery polling) while processing the data on the server?
2. or should I use a a delayed job to store the file temporary on S3 and the pass the URL? is it worth for a file that is going to be used once?

My code:

```
send_data(zip(@data), :filename => "name.zip", :type=>"application/zip")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to avoid the dreaded Heroku [H12 request timeout error.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout)

There are a couple ways of doing this.

1. The slacker method is to send back spaces to let Heroku know that you are alive and sending data. You'll need to modify your code to write a space every once in a while, but that will be enough to keep Heroku from timing out, but also not interfere with the data later. You'll need to set the headers correctly since you can't modify headers after you've sent data on the wire.
2. You can have your client poll every couple seconds (I highly recommend exponential backoff for almost all things polling). You'll need to create a new endpoint like `/status`, that the webapp can request. However, this means that when the original zipped file request finishes, there is no way for the server to communicate back to the client as the connection has long been killed. Thus, you upload the file to s3 and then when the client asks for /status, you check if the file has been uploaded to s3 and then return the url.

If you are concerned about how to manage space on S3, I recommend looking at [S3 object expiration](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/) which will automatically delete files after a certain lifespan.

Comment: is the slacker method something i can implement for a single controller action? could you reference an example of how to implement the slacker method?

Comment: Hmm. So I failed to find a good writeup on the space method. I would suggest that you try the simple exercise of keeping a request open for a really long time by sending a space, not closing the connection, sleeping for a couple seconds, and then sending back a new space. This request will stay unfinished, since it will extend the browser timeout and heroku timeouts. From there, you can extend it to be zipping up your file while you send back spaces. This bandaid is not really recommended because sooner or later, you are going to run into issues with this as it's fairly brittle.

Comment: do you have any example of how to keep connection open by sending spaces?